# Do odexed programs have any runtime (vs load time) performance gains?

Tags: custom-roms, performance

From my understanding, odexed programs are programs that are pre-compiled for specific architecture.

It is obvious that this process would help decrease the startup time for the program.

Am I correct in thinking that odexing would have **NO** effect on the performance of the program once it is already loaded in memory? What about memory footprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect it to have an impact on both.  An odexed app is optimized, not just precompiled.  Android runs on a huge variety of hardware, so platform-specific optimizations could result in significant performance gains.